# Python - Merging bundles in floweaver

Tags: python, sankey-diagram

I have a list of clicks on a website for a set of users. I'm trying to create a flow of clicks through the website. With the code below I get the following result. **I'd like to have the end of the first bundle be joined with the end of the second bundle,** otherwise it just looks weird.

```
import floweaver as fw
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={'event_no': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3],
          'source': ['Home', 'Home', 'Home', 'Products', 'Products', 'Products', 'About', 'About', 'Product1', 'Product1'],
          'target': ['About', 'Products', 'Other', 'Product1', 'Product2', 'Product3', 'Products', 'Other', 'Buy', 'Buy'],
          'value': [100, 300, 150, 150, 75, 50, 50, 10, 20, 10]}
)

size = {'width': 600, 'height': 600}
nodes = {
    'Event1': fw.ProcessGroup(df.loc[df['event_no'] == 1, 'source'].unique().tolist()),
    'Event2': fw.ProcessGroup(df.loc[df['event_no'] == 2, 'source'].unique().tolist()),
    'Event3': fw.ProcessGroup(df.loc[df['event_no'] == 3, 'source'].unique().tolist())
}
ordering = [
    ['Event1'],
    ['Event2'],
    ['Event3']
]
bundles = [
    fw.Bundle('Event1', 'Event2'),
    fw.Bundle('Event2', 'Event3')
]
nodes['Event1'].partition = fw.Partition.Simple('source', df.loc[df['event_no'] == 1, 'source'].unique())
nodes['Event2'].partition = fw.Partition.Simple('source', df.loc[df['event_no'] == 2, 'source'].unique())
nodes['Event3'].partition = fw.Partition.Simple('source', df.loc[df['event_no'] == 3, 'source'].unique())

sdd = fw.SankeyDefinition(nodes, bundles, ordering)
fw.weave(sdd, df).to_widget(**size)
```

[image]

I tried using a waypoint which works when I have only one event in between, but for some reason it won't work when I have 4+ event_no and use [2, 3, ...] as waypoints.

Any ideas how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

When you partition, you need to use the `process` class. Change each of the three to: `fw.Partition.Simple('process', df.loc[df['event_no'] == 1, 'source'].unique())` and you will be set.